# How to access the control registers cr0,cr2,cr3 from a program? Getting segmentation fault

Tags: x86, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

I have written a program which tries to read from and write to the control registers.

The program compiles fine, but when the inline assembly is about to be executed, it produces a segmentation fault.

Code:

```
void instructions(int val)
{
    int i;
    int value;
    for(i = 0; i < val; i++)
         __asm__("mov %cr0, %eax");
}
```

I used GDB and stepped through each assembly line and it is on the `mov %cr0,%eax` that the segmentation fault is occurring.

Anyone who knows what is wrong?

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚威视 You do realize this question is 4 years old?  Chris hasn't been seen since 2011.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I do. Maybe some day he will come back. I'm not waiting for him to answer. Questions on SO are useful forever. I often answer those, and some times got rep.  :-)

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I found everything said in here useful (:

Answer (score 21):

Quoting from [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals 3-650 Vol. 2A](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)
 on moving to and from control registers:

> This instruction can be executed only when the current privilege level is 0.

Which means the instruction can only be executed in kernel mode.

A minimal kernel module, that logs the contents of cr0, cr2 and cr3 could look something like this (32-bit code path untested):

```
/* hello.c */
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

int init_module(void)
{
#ifdef __x86_64__
    u64 cr0, cr2, cr3;
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "mov %%cr0, %%rax\n\t"
        "mov %%eax, %0\n\t"
        "mov %%cr2, %%rax\n\t"
        "mov %%eax, %1\n\t"
        "mov %%cr3, %%rax\n\t"
        "mov %%eax, %2\n\t"
    : "=m" (cr0), "=m" (cr2), "=m" (cr3)
    : /* no input */
    : "%rax"
    );
#elif defined(__i386__)
    u32 cr0, cr2, cr3;
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "mov %%cr0, %%eax\n\t"
        "mov %%eax, %0\n\t"
        "mov %%cr2, %%eax\n\t"
        "mov %%eax, %1\n\t"
        "mov %%cr3, %%eax\n\t"
        "mov %%eax, %2\n\t"
    : "=m" (cr0), "=m" (cr2), "=m" (cr3)
    : /* no input */
    : "%eax"
    );
#endif
    printk(KERN_INFO "cr0 = 0x%8.8X\n", cr0);
    printk(KERN_INFO "cr2 = 0x%8.8X\n", cr2);
    printk(KERN_INFO "cr3 = 0x%8.8X\n", cr3);
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
}
```

```
# Makefile

obj-m += hello.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean

test: all
    sudo insmod ./hello.ko
    sudo rmmod hello
    dmesg | tail
```

Comment: Did you mean `u64`? At least `cr3` is documented in the intel manuals for intel 64 from bits 0 : 63.

Comment: @corny: It was just a quick example to show how to access the control registers, so for simplicity I only print the lower 32-bits even in 64-bit mode. I think all the control registers are 64-bit in long mode and you definitely want all bits of CR2/CR3 if you're actually doing something useful with the contents.

Comment: Correct, in 64 bit mode, all control registers are 64 bit. Section 2.5, “CONTROL REGISTERS” in the Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 3A. I edited your answer, let's delete our comment and let's just preserve your improved answer.

Comment: I don't currently have a way to easily check the code, but I think the format string should to be `%016lx` in 64-bit mode (or perhaps `%p` can be used if cr0/cr2/cr3 are cast to `void*`)

Comment: As it is a 64-bit register it should be %016llx (additional long).

Comment: @user786653 - Will you show how to write to `cr0`? I can read, but get segmentation fault when writing to it.