# Disable CPU caches (L1/L2) on ARMv8-A Linux

Tags: linux, caching, arm

I want to disable the low level cache on an ARMv8-A platform running Linux, in order to measure performance of optimized code, independent of cache access.

For Intel systems I found the following resource ([Is there a way to disable CPU cache (L1/L2) on a Linux system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948542/is-there-a-way-to-disable-cpu-cache-l1-l2-on-a-linux-system)), but I can not directly be applied directly due to a different instruction set.

So far I have a kernel module which alters the corresponding system register to disable instruction and data cache.

```
#include <linux/module.h>

int init_module(void)
{
  int64_t value;

  asm volatile("\
    MRS %0, SCTLR_EL1     // Read SCTLR_EL1 into Xt\n\
    BIC %0, %0, (1<<2)    // clear bit 2, SCTLR_EL1.C\n\
    BIC %0, %0, (1<<12)   // clear bit 12, SCTLR_EL1.I\n\
    MSR SCTLR_EL1, %0     // Write Xt to SCTLR_EL1\n\
  " : "+r" (value));

  return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
  int64_t value;

  asm volatile("\
    MRS %0, SCTLR_EL1    // Read SCTLR_EL1 into Xt\n\
    ORR %0, %0, (1<<2)   // set bit 2, SCTLR_EL1.C\n\
    ORR %0, %0, (1<<12)  // set bit 12, SCTLR_EL1.I\n\
    MSR SCTLR_EL1, %0    // Write Xt to SCTLR_EL1\n\
  ": "+r" (value));
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

However it results in a complete system freeze when loaded (when I set the corresponding bits in the system register). My guess is that I still need some kind of cache clear, but I didn't find anything useful in the ARM manuals.

Anyone has some helpful hints how I could succeed in disabling the cache on ARM or what I am missing here? Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this already? http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0438f/BABHEJFF.html

Comment: and this:) https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/973472/how-to-write-bits-to-registers-in-order-to-disable-cache-/?offset=5

Comment: I have seen it done on armv6, it was a royal PITA, and we slammed into ldrex/strex problems (you dip into the chip vendor memory controller rather than arms so it is chip specific if exclusive access is implemented at all or correctly).  I dont know if the AXI/AMBA changes too much for armv8 to know if the bus accesses you need for protection and mmu are generated with the caches disabled.

Comment: you will need to sprinkle a bunch of memory barriers about and flush the caches and stuff you cant simply turn the bits off.  Better yet attack it from the perspective of removing the code that turns them on in the first place.

Comment: @HRgiger thanks for the links, they are for older architecture versions but seem to show exactly the problems I was facing

Comment: @old_timer thank you for the hint, maybe I can find the place where they are enabled

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, this is unworkable, for several reasons.

Firstly, clearing the SCTLR.C bit only makes all data accesses non-cacheable. and prevents *allocating* into any caches. Any data in the caches is still there in the caches, especially dirty lines from anything recently-written; consider what happens when your function returns and the caller tries to restore a stack frame which doesn't even exist in the memory it's now accessing.

Secondly, there are very few uniprocessor ARMv8 systems; assuming you're running SMP Linux, and suddenly disable the caches on just whichever CPU the module loader happened to be scheduled on, then even disregarding the first point things are going to go downhill very fast. Linux expects all CPUs to be coherent with each other, and will typically become very broken very rapidly if that assumption is violated. Note that it's not even worth venturing into SMP cross-calling for this; suffice to say the only *safe* way to even attempt to run Linux with caches disabled is to make sure they are never enabled to begin with, except...

Thirdly, there is no guarantee Linux will even run with caches disabled. On current hardware, all of the locking and atomic operations in the kernel (not to mention userspace) rely on the exclusive access instructions. Whilst the CPU cluster(s) will implement the architecturally-required local and global exclusive monitors for cacheable memory (usually as part of the cache machinery itself), it is dependent on the system whether a global exclusive monitor for non-cacheable accesses is implemented, as such a thing must be external to the CPU (usually in the interconnect or memory controller). Many systems don't implement such a global monitor, in which case exclusive accesses to external memory may fault, do nothing, or other various implementation-defined behaviours which will result in Linux crashing or deadlocking. It is effectively impossible to run Linux with the cache off on such a system - the amount of hacking just to get a UP arm64 kernel to work (SMP would be literally impossible) would be impractical alone; good luck with userspace.

As it happens, though, the worst problem is none of that, it's this:

> ...in order to measure performance of optimized code, independent of cache access.

If the code is intended to run in deployment with caches disabled, then logically it can't be intended to run under Linux, therefore the effort spent in hacking up Linux would be better spent on benchmarking in a more realistic execution environment so that results are actually representative. On the other hand, if it *is* intended to run with caches enabled (under Linux or any other OS), then benchmarking with caches disabled will give meaningless results and be a waste of time. "Optimising" for e.g. an instruction-fetch-bandwidth bottleneck which won't exist in practice is not going to lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, it definitely shows the reasons why disabling the cache did not succeed. So one last try could be to disable the cache enable part in the kernel source, but I also see your points why this will also be tricky.

Comment: The goal essentially was to have fixed run-times, to have an optimized, constant time code. So this is why the cache would be harmful in the testing environment to prove the constant time execution.

Comment: If you _really_ want to bypass the D-cache, it would be a lot simpler to just hack `mmap`/`mprotect` to let you set up some non-cacheable memory in your process to operate on. Disabling the I-cache will achieve little other than throwing all performance out of the window, plus any 'optimisation' that makes things slightly less slow in that situation is liable to make real-world performance _worse_.

Comment: This could essentially be the solution to my problem. Could you maybe add some details on how to do this? I also saw something on cachability hints in the ARM architecture reference, but I did not find anything on how to use them. Are they related to your approach?

Comment: In general, "constant time" normally means "not data dependent", and any decent benchmarking tool should account for cache effects anyway. Execution in perfectly constant _wallclock_ time is unlikely to be possible on modern hardware, and especially not under Linux - you'd have to get rid of the OS, external I/O, interrupts, etc., at which point you have to start wondering how meaningful any results would be.

Comment: I don't actually "know" how - I'm just surmising that, say, an anonymous `mmap` will give you some memory mapped with `pgprot_cached`, thus it ought to be fairly straightforward to bodge in some flag that makes it use `pgprot_writecombine` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it on armv8-a linux. I do it not to measure performance but to verify that xilinx zcu104 platform might have potential coherence error. As a result, the pynq image xilinx provided must have some coherence error during pl and ps communication. 
Here is my workaround:

1. My platform is cortex-a53, ubuntu18 started at EL2 and switched to EL1 and supported SMP on four cpu cores. Thus, I need to turn off multi-core to ensure L2-cache coherency. Thanks to the feature of cpu-hot-plug, I just run :

   echo '0' > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online,

   echo '0' > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/online,

   echo '0' > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/online

   then I run dmesg to verify that multi-core has been turn off.
2. I build the kernel source tree, cause I cannot find it in my linux. You can run uname -r to see your kernel version. And find in /usr/src to see whether your linux already have it.
3. I build the linux module. With gcc inline asm , I flush all cache and set sctlr_el1.c 0.
4. I insmod the module. And I first run my program with the right result, although it takes 20 times slower than multi-core and D-cache on.